# How can I call this php function in html

Tags: php, html

I am building a social site where users are able to see notifications when someone follow/unfollow them. 
There is a function provided in the purchased plugin which notifies/alerts users on number of notifications.

```
/*
 * Helper functions
 *
 * Use these functions inside themes to display various notification-related information
 */


 function ip_notifications_menu_item() {
        if(notification_count() > 0)
            $item = '<a href="#" class="notifications-bell">
<i class="fa fa-bell"></i><sup>' . notification_count() . '</sup></a>
<div class="notifications-container">' . do_shortcode('[notifications]') . '</div>';
        else
            $item = '<a href="#" class="notifications-bell">
<i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i></a><div class="notifications-container">' . do_shortcode('[notifications]') . '</div>';

        return $item;
    }
```

How can I call this on the menu item I have created for notifications?

Much appreciate your help!

Comment: use ajax through javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX method to get data from php functions as your page doesn't want to reload to get those data.

ajax call example (jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'test.php',
  data: { postVar1: exp1, postVar2: exp2 },
  beforeSend:function(){
    // this is where we append a loading image
   // $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
   alert('...requesting');
  },
  success:function(data){
    alert(data);
  },
  error:function(){
    // failed request; give feedback to user
    alert('ERROR');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the function in html using AJAX as follows..
 As i am using jquery ajax...

```
$.get('yourpage.php',function(data){
 alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn" onclick="onrequest();">Show Notification</button>

function onrequest() {
      $.post('notificationfile.php').success(function(response){
           // you can use this response as you wish
            alert(response);
       });
}
```

Note: Replace notificationfile.php with actual/full path of the file.

**And inside notificationfile.php put your code**

```
/*
 * Helper functions
 *
 * Use these functions inside themes to display various notification-related information
 */


 function ip_notifications_menu_item() {
     if(notification_count() > 0)
        $item = '<a href="#" class="notifications-bell">
<i class="fa fa-bell"></i><sup>' . notification_count() . '</sup></a>
<div class="notifications-container">' . do_shortcode('[notifications]') . '</div>';
        else
            $item = '<a href="#" class="notifications-bell">
<i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i></a><div class="notifications-container">' . do_shortcode('[notifications]') . '</div>';

        return $item;
    }
```

Hope this will help you!!